# SQL Server Insert hangs - blocked by a process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

when i try to run an insert within an application, it hangs and eventually times out.

i ran the EXEC SP_WHO2 while it was still running and noticed that it was blocked by another process and there was a "lock" in the "wait type"

what does this mean? how do i fix it? i'm so lost.

the process that was in the "Blocked By" field had a delete statement in it. i validated the statement and it works fine.

Comment: Does this happen for you consistently or did it seem to be a one-time occurrence?

Comment: it keeps happening every time i try to "save" a record in the application.

Comment: Well it means that there is an open transaction that owns a conflicting lock (possibly table lock) that is blocking your insert. Impossible to know from here whether it is still busy doing work or has been left open hanging uncommitted.

Comment: my delete is using a different table, that has no relationship to the one i'm trying to update.

Comment: It could have aquired the lock from an earlier statement in the same transaction then (Assuming no triggers or cascading deletes etc)

Comment: so, what can i do to fix this from happening? does this mean the real issue is in the delete statement that locks up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your previous transaction is in open state due to some error in your stored procedure which prevents commiting /rollbacking the transaction in the absence of exception handling. This causes the table locking and application
gets hang in next request 
Below is the recommended approach...

```
set xact_abort on
Begin Try
  Begin Tran
    //SQl Query
  Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
   Rollback Tran
End Catch
```